# I'm trying to set up a home network but i have no idea what hardware to purchase

Tags: networking

I have an internet connection running into a router and then an ethernet wire running to a room on the other side of the house.  This room has 3 devices that need to be connected to the internet.  However, I only have one wire that can be ran from the main router (due to space).

What can I use to split this wire into 3 so I can connect all the devices to the internet?  I've done some basic reading and I'm hearing a lot about using switches, would that work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any small switch will work. There are several models out there ranging from $25 or so on up to over $150. I would look for something in the neighborhood of a 5 port workgroup switch in the brand of Netgear or Linksys. Even belkin would be okay.

Answer (score 3):

Wait-a-minute...

You know that long wire you have running from the router into that room with three devices?  Why can't you use that long wire to connect the router to your internet connection... and just put the router in that room?  The router most likely has 4 LAN ports, which would allow you to connect those three devices.

I mean, based on the information you have provided, this would be a solution that would take care of your problem.

I know... you are going to reply with reasons why you can't move the router, as you have things in the room that it is connected to, which would prompt me to ask why you didn't supply that information in the first place... and the back and forth will go on a little more until it seems that you have to either purchase a network switch or another router to use as an access point.

Comment: aha your last paragraph couldn't have been more right, but thanks for the advice anyways!